# Just Typing "python --version" Causes Python to Crash

Tags: python

In the past, I have used python3 with no issues. However, after updating to the latest version of Mac Os, I am having issues. When I type "which python3" I get this: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
However, I soon as I type "python --version" I get this error:
[image]

Then I get an error that python crashed unexpectedly. I have been trying for hours be I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: What about `python3 --version`?

Comment: From what it looks like, that's an incomplete installation. I'm guessing `python3` by itself doesn't work either. I'd try removing it and reinstalling it, or perhaps use `brew install python3`.

Comment: Actually python3 --version does work. It seems to be a problem with Visual Studio now. My Interpreter says I am running my version of python, but when I hit the run button in VS, it automatically tries running with just "python" and not "python3"